# Objective C to Swift Methods call?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Here is my objective c method call that I need to convert to a swift call.

It's complaining that "Could not find an overload for logInWithUsernameInBackground that accepts the supplied arguments.

What am I doing wrong?

Objective C Method Decleration

```
typedef void (^PFUserResultBlock)(PFUser *user, NSError *error);

+ (void)logInWithUsernameInBackground:(NSString *)username
                             password:(NSString *)password
                                block:(PFUserResultBlock)block;
```

Objective C Call

```
[User logInWithUsernameInBackground:@""
                            password:@""
                               block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"test");
 }];
```

Swift

```
User.logInWithUsernameInBackground("", 
  password: "", 
     block: { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError) -> Void in
       NSLog("test")
    }
)
```

Comment: Please show the _declaration_ of this method in Objective-C. That, not how you were calling it, is what's important.

Comment: `{ (user, error) in NSLog("test")}`

Comment: Added method definition to my question

Comment: @BryanChen Can you submit that as an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let compiler figure out the correct type for you with type inference

```
User.logInWithUsernameInBackground("", 
  password: "", 
     block: {
     (user, error) in
         NSLog("test")
    } 
)
```

Comment: Objective c used to autocomplete the block definition for you. Doesn't seem like this is happening for closures in swift