# short piece of code Swift error: not convertible to PFUserResultBlock

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this error "not convertible to PFUserResultBlock" in this piece of code I have here in Xcode-Swift:

[image: error in xcode]

Does anyone possibly know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Please provide the specification for PFUserResultBlock, it is not a standard framework and so not all of us will be familiar.

Comment: Does this help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900090/objective-c-to-swift-methods-call

Comment: You are more likely to get answers to your question if you include the code/errors in text rather than an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the `typedef` of `PFUserResultBlock`

```
typedef void (^PFUserResultBlock)(PFUser *PF_NULLABLE_S user, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
```

please change your code to

```
PFTwitterUtils.logInWithBlock { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

so that the `PF_NULLABLE_S` annotation is respected.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all and specially Daniel. Daniel's solution worked for me.
Also, in the previous picture where I first asked the question, I had typed everything manually. When using the typing autocomplete feature of Xcode what Daniel has suggested shows up and code works.
I have a picture of what worked for me in the case someone else will look at this post in future:
[twitter login in xcode 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqPvT.png)

Following Hayley suggestion:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseTwitterUtils

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

//    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
//        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
//    
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
//    }

@IBAction func loginWithTwitterTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

     PFTwitterUtils.initializeWithConsumerKey("XWvwtGCsXKkz3yAjKJpCv6mOA", consumerSecret:"gmSVhubFvVl1dILSxfRiCCkTb9PfPAcoCyN3i2SS6JgD5up3cz")

     PFTwitterUtils.logInWithBlock { (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if user == nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("WE DID IT")
        }
    }   
}
```

}